# How to logically combine pathMatchers in spring security

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to setup a Spring Security for a WebFlux project in kotlin. Let's say I have the following endpoint:

- `/departments/{deptId}/users`

And I need to allow access to it, if both below checks are true:

- if user has access to the given deptId
- if user has UserManagement authority.

I can make them work separately, but I cannot find a way to combine (logical AND) them together:
I'd like to return 403 if

- user has right, but doesn't have access
- user has access, but doesn't have right
  and return 200 if has access and has right

The code below ignores the first check - it only checks if user has user management right:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain =
    http
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtConverter).and()
        .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/departments/{deptId}/**").access(hasAccessToDept)
        .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(
            "/departments/{deptId}/users*",
            "/departments/{deptId}/users/*")
        .hasAuthority(USER_MANAGEMENT)
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .build()
```

Comment: what do you mean by `right` and `access` do you mean has the proper `role` and the proper `authority`?

Comment: by `access` I mean the custom implementation of `ReactiveAuthorizationManager`, which I use in `.access` method. By right I mean authority.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at „expression based security“. With this you can put expressions on the corresponding Controller method. You have access to arguments and return values as well and I like especially that the definitions are close to the code they will be applied to.

```
@PreAutorize(„hasRole(...)“)
```

or

```
@PostAuthorize(...)
```

Here‘s the link to the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html

EDIT:

You can probably use expressions also in the filter configuration like this:

```
    authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").access("@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)")
```

Comment: It's a webflux application in kotlin, there is no controllers - I have handlers, which receives a ServerRequest. Not sure annotations can be applied in this case

Comment: I just realized you are using that. What is the content of `hassaccessDept`. In that bean you can inject the SecurityContext and grab the user roles too.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it works, however it's not as elegant as I planned :) I was hoping that I can combine pathMatchers in a kind of a logical AND expression chain. So for a request to `/depts/{deptId}/users` it would check first pathMatcher (/depts/{deptId}, if it's true, check the next one `/depts/{deptId}/users`. If one of them is false - return 403. Anyway thanks for the suggestion! I'll wait for few days, and will post what I have ended up with.

Comment: Ah I see. Nope. As far as I know it‘s just the first match that takes over. 

Just educational: Probably you can invert the PathMatcher definition so the most specific is the first. Then you call the filterchain with the shorter path yourself in your access evaluation? Not sure how performant that would be :)